# Client error: `BAN http://varnish` resulted in a `405 Not allowed` response

Tags: kubernetes, api-platform.com

I have installed a k8s cluster on AWS with kops and I have followed instructions to deploy api-platform on that cluster with helm.

I don't understand why the php pod log shows a 405 when php-pod try to invalidate cache into varnish-pod.

In the Varnish pod inside /usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl my whitelist is the default one

```
# Hosts allowed to send BAN requests
acl invalidators {
  "localhost";
  "php";
}
```

UPDATE I think that the problem can be generalized in this way: from a pod A inside a service A I want to call a service B. I need that in the request (received in pod B) is preserved the IP of the service A not the IP of the pod A.

Comment: What instructions did you follow to deploy the api-platform?

Comment: Here is the full guide I wrote https://gist.github.com/mmeloni/64b268929d6f9074ee9d8f165845db23

Answer (score 1):

My original problem can be  summarize with:

from a pod A inside a service A I want to call a service B. I need that in the request (received in pod B) is preserved in the origin the IP  of the service A not the IP of the pod A.

But Kubernetes networking model need that:

- all containers can communicate with all other containers without NAT
- all nodes can communicate with all containers (and vice-versa) without NAT
- the IP that a container sees itself as is the same IP that others see it as

So my needed can't be satisfied.

So my solution is to use https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/ and not to rely to a ip-based whitelist in the varnish vcl config.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier fix from api-platform: https://github.com/api-platform/demo/blob/master/api/docker/varnish/conf/default.vcl#L22-L25

I think they will update the helm chart with this one

Comment: Links are great, but it would be even more helpful if you could summarize a possible way to correct the problem outlined in the question.

Comment: Yes the content is gone now, 404 :(